# Why is there an extra HDD under /dev being added in my Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I have created a Linux kernel and for some reason an extra drive is always added at bootup.

My hard drive is listed as `/dev/sdb`.  `/dev/sda` is created too, and it is 8 MB in size.  I can't find anything in the kernel config that is creating this, but if I use a different kernel it is not there. Kernel logs show it as an attached SCSI device, looks just like my hard drive but only 8 MB, and has no partition table. It also doesn't appear to be a physical device. I've tried the kernel on many different models of PCs and it is always there.

Does anyone know how to remove it?

---

`/dev/disk/by-id` gives me:

```
scsi-1AMCC_U21413034D98EB000584 
scsi-1AMCC_U21413034D98EB000584-part1 
scsi-353333330000007d0 
scsi-SATA_ST3250312AS_5VY7SH42 
scsi-SATA_WDC_WD800JD-60L_WD-WMAM9Y085675 
scsi-SATA_WDC_WD800JD-60L_WD-WMAM9Y085675-part1 
scsi-SATA_WDC_WD800JD-60L_WD-WMAM9Y085675-part2
```

`hdparm -i /dev/sda` gives me an "invalid argument".

`dd if=/dev/sda of=sda.img` the resulting file does not have any content

`sdparm results:`

> ```
> /dev/sda: Linux     scsi_debug        0004 Device identification VPD page:   Addressed logical unit:
> designator type: T10 vendor identification,  code set: ASCII
>   vendor id: Linux   
>   vendor specific: scsi_debug      2000
> designator type: NAA,  code set: Binary
>   0x53333330000007d0   Target port:
> designator type: Relative target port,  code set: Binary
>  transport: Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
>   Relative target port: 0x1
> designator type: NAA,  code set: Binary
>  transport: Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
>   0x52222220000007ce
> designator type: Target port group,  code set: Binary
>  transport: Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
>   Target port group: 0x100   Target device that contains addressed lu:
> designator type: NAA,  code set: Binary
>  transport: Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
>   0x52222220000007cd
> designator type: SCSI name string,  code set: UTF-8
>  transport: Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
>   SCSI name string:
>   naa.52222220000007CD
> ```

Comment: What happens if you `dd if=/dev/sda of=sda.img`? Does the resulting `sda.img` file have any content?

Comment: If it is not an ATA device, hdparm naturally fails. You should use `sdparm -i /dev/sda` for block devices using the SCSI layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you enabled a [SCSI debug device](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdebug26.html) while you were creating your kernel?